# A Numpy error, seemingly unrelated to the script which throws it, that does not show up on the debugger

Tags: python

So I have `foo`, an ordinary tuple of ordinary floats. Calling map on it in my script is inexplicably throwing a Numpy error of all things, even though there's nothing wrong with the code. Going into the debugger and executing the exact same code produces no errors as expected. Does anyone have any idea what could be going on? I'm at a complete loss. How is any of this possible?

Also, to those asking for a minimal script to reproduce the issue: I am unable to reproduce it using short snippets, and I can't post the whole script because it is for a homework assignment.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "py_code\ps4-code.py", line 240, in <module>
    doPairMatch(transA, transB, tapoints, tbpoints, 1, ransacTranslate)
  File "py_code\ps4-code.py", line 217, in doPairMatch
    print map(int, foo)
TypeError: expected a single-segment buffer object
>>> import pdb;pdb.pm()
> c:\homework\cs4495\ps4\py_code\ps4-code.py(217)doPairMatch()
-> print map(int, foo)
(Pdb) print foo
(603.0, 437.0)
(Pdb) print map(int, foo)
[603, 437]
(Pdb) print type(foo)
<type 'tuple'>
(Pdb) print int, map, type
<type 'int'> <built-in function map> <type 'type'>
(Pdb) map(type, foo)
[<type 'float'>, <type 'float'>]
(Pdb)
```

Edit: Well at least I figured out how this is possible. It appears that the problem is occurring during garbage collection, which is why the errors were randomly appearing in unrelated parts of code. Presumably, the gc is triggering a bug somewhere in OpenCV causing everything to crash.

```
Exception TypeError: 'expected a single-segment buffer object' in 'garbage colle
ction' ignored
Fatal Python error: unexpected exception during garbage collection

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Comment: Showing us it working as expected at a prompt isn't going to help us work out why it *isn't* working in your script.

Comment: Well what else can I do? I have no idea what could possibly be happening, so I figured someone on Stack Overflow might know.

Comment: post a short (minimal!) script which reproduces the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't figured out any way to reproduce it yet, other than running the script. And it's for homework, so I don't think I can just post the whole thing.

Comment: Can you at least post the lines on which it is throwing the error?  240 and 217, plus where the data used on those lines is defined?  Also, what version of python are you using?

Comment: The lines are in the traceback. It's just `print map(int, foo)`. `foo` comes from the pt attribute of an OpenCV KeyPoint. Actually, I'm beginning to wonder if the problem is due to code being called during garbage collection, possibly with a bug in OpenCV. That would explain how it's magically throwing an unrelated error.

Comment: +1 to you for finding the source of error - don't think that would have ever crossed my mind.

Answer (score 1):

I know this kind of exceptions from a different cause: a buggy C extension module (OpenCV?).  If the TypeError is raised during the execution of some C function from this module, but the module is missing the code to detect it, then it can remain undetected past the execution of the C function.  It will suddenly show up a bit later.

I have no way of knowing if I'm correct, but a good indicator would be if there is a call to such a C extension module a few lines before the "map(int, foo)".  One way to know for sure is to put just before this "map(int, foo)" another line that would detect a left-behind exception.  As it turns out, it can be for example "all([])".  If you get the TypeError on the "all([])" line, then obviously it is a left-behind exception.